# Use select statement as the limit to the outer select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking to get the top half of a table, I set a select statement that returns an integer as the limit to the outer select statement and got a syntax error.

I checked and ran the select statements separately and they work fine.

My questions are:
1.confirm that the limit cannot be another select statement? 
2.If above is true, what the alternative ways to get the top half of the table

```
select lat_n from station order by lat_n 
limit (select ceil(count(*)/2) from station);
```

Result:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '(select ceil(count(*)/2) from station)' at
>   line 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative:

```
select t.lat_n 
from (
  select lat_n, @rownum:=@rownum+1 rn 
  from station, (select @rownum:=0) r
  order by lat_n
) t
where t.rn <= (select count(*) from station) / 2
```

The variable `@rownum` as a counter pseudocolumn is used so to select only the 1st half rows of the table.

Answer (score 0):

> LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be
>   nonnegative integer **constants**

From the reference manual entry for SELECT [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Thanks! Scanned the documentation before and must be blind to miss the constant part!

Comment: Sometimes that stuff is easy to overlook.